# Auth0 custom claims

Tags: jwt, auth0

Im thinking of using Auth0 for my API and web application and have a query  . When the Jwt token is generated I would like to include some custom user claims that only exist in my user database. Is this possible or do all claims need to exist as pre-defined attributes in Auth0.

I have my own user database because there are some dynamic and complicated user permissions that I need to store there. I realize that one option is not to store these permissions in the token and I could have a separate api to get them but for performance and simplicity I'd rather wrap them into the Jwt token.  I can't seem to see a way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: JWT allows for any arbitrary claims.

Comment: Thanks. I do realize that.jwt supports any claims. My question is does auth0 have hooks to allow me to add in custom claims from my own user store during token generation.

Comment: Yes, you can do that using Rules and custom claims, see https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/current/custom-claims and https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **Rules** and **Custom Claims**, and they don't have to be predefined or even persistent in a user profile.

See

- https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/current/custom-claims
- https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims

for docs and examples.